# canvas with timer

Tags: android, canvas

I didn't know how to name my problem,
however I'm trying to display some text with canvas for a period of time everytime user clicks a square, I have been trying with timer

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
       }
    }, 11000);
```

but this is working just for the first click, second dissapears immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {....},
                       0,        //initial delay
                       11000);  //subsequent rate
```

Comment: Thanks, however still the same issue, first click works, second and so on, does not

Comment: Then maybe you could post how you draw the text

Comment: Maybe the issue is not with the timer but with the click?

Comment: if(show) {canvas.drawText("-50", 50, 50, paint);     timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

         public void run() {

          show=false;

         }

      },0, 11000);
   }  and after every click the state of show is changed to true

Comment: You may want to put if(show) { drawText() } inside your timer task